# Entity Framework 4.2 enum support

Tags: entity-framework-4

Does EF 4.2 Code First have support for enum types?  If so, how do you use it?  The following does not create a field for the enum property when using the Nuget EntityFramework package.

```
public class FooContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; } 
}

public class Foo
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public enum Category {One, Two, Three }

var db = new FooContext();
db.Foos.ToList();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EF team [has changed versioning](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/08/09/ef-releases-amp-versioning-call-for-feedback.aspx) so EFv4.2 is not final release of June 2011 CTP. Features from June 2011 CTP [should be released as part of .NET Framework 4.5](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/10/ef-4-5-is-coming-in-the-next-net-4-5-developer-preview/).

Answer (score 2):

No.

The enum support and many more features were included in the "June 2011 CTP" preview ([see announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx%24)) - but those require changes to the EF core and those will be shipped later.

EF 4.2 is only a few bugfixes and smaller changes - see [ADO.NET team blog announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/01/ef-4-2-released.aspx).

> *What’s Not in This Release?*
>
> As covered earlier this release is just a small update to the
>   DbContext & Code First runtime. **The features that were included in EF
>   June 2011 CTP require changes to the Core Entity Framework Libraries
>   that are part of the .NET Framework and will ship at a later date.**